# How can I skip the first level of Eggmanland?

Tags: ps3, sonic-unleashed

Is there any way to skip the first level of the last continent (Eggmanland)?

I'm asking because I've tried numerous times to beat it and it is ridiclously difficult to pass. There are six parts, alternating between the normal Sonic and werehog Sonic forms and every time I try, I need at least an hour, maybe an hour and a half to get to the third time you are a werehog, before dying there and having to start all over.

It just seems way too difficult to bother anymore. I've let the game rot at the last continent for a very long time now, but I was wondering if anyone would know of any (cheating) way to get past this?

I do want to try the bosses after this level though, I'm not looking for a way to just skip to the ending (though this is preferable to no solution at all).

update:
Does anyone have any hints or tips to help me beat this level? Should I just go back and level my stats some more (though that wasn't why I died, it was the damn platforming and stupid camera angles getting in the way)..?

Comment: Retagged for the correct game.  Also, I haven't beaten this game yet but this sounds a LOT like the ending of Sonic Adventure 2, which also gave me a terrible time.

Comment: @Shinrai: Pretty much. The main differences are that Eggmanland in Unleashed isn't timed and you only switch between two variations of Sonic. What's interesting is that hourglasses are involved in both Cannon's Core in SA2 and Eggmanland in Unleashed!

Answer (score 1):

I have watched a pretty easy video on Walkthrough for XBOX but i am pretty sure it works for PS3 too
http://bit.ly/SonicEggManLandXbox

Comment: makes it look easy, but I know how hard the level is when actually playing it. Nevertheless, best answer, I'll try the video walkthrough, trying to see what'll come ahead every time. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say to go through the level one check point at a time. pause the game after avery checkpoint and/or battle and refresh urself before picking the remote up. also, never get angry at the game. it is about timing an memorization. and have fun